# index scan in MS SQL execution plan when using non cluster index in where clause instead of index seek

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, performance, indexing

In my project, stored procedures for searching are as follows

```
create proc CommentGet
(
@Type int,
@ParentID int
)

as
begin
select * from CommentTable where (@Type is null or CommentTable.Type=@Type) and (@ParentID is null or CommentTable.ParentID=@ParentID) 
end
```

In this case, I introduced Type and ParentID as non-cluster index for CommentTable. When I run the code, I see the Execution plan using a Index Scan instead of a Index Seek for getting result that causes SQL to need to read whole pages. And apparently I can not use the non-cluster indexing benefits.

As I have figured out so far, if the variable is used in the search term, this problem occurs, and if the direct amount of the where clues  is not used, the problem does not arise and it works correctly (index Seek).

Please advise you on how to use the non-cluster index benefits to handle it
[Here exception plane as example, as you see written index scan instead of index Seek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpPxq.png)

Comment: Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE);` to the end of your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: This is what's known as a "catch-all query". I suggest having a read of Gail's article's on these: [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [Revisiting Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

Comment: You have a column called `CommentTable` in a table called `CommentTable`? I'm guessing this isn't your actual SQL; which makes it very difficult to say anything about it.

Comment: Rather than describing the plan to us, can you [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) instead?

Comment: @DanGuzman what exactly do this option? is make reduce performance of SP?

Comment: @Larnu I test that select as query also and execution plan not changed, i don't think this problem was in chasing area

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i fixed

Comment: What is a "chasing area"?

Comment: @Larnu I think the problem is not related to the caching field

Comment: Why, when there are plenty of articles out there explaining why a catch-all query without the right `OPTION` or not compiled as Dynamic SQL performs badly. This is one of those times. Why do you believe the opposite to what plenty of exports have proven the opposite of.

Comment: As I have figured out so far, if the variable is used in the search term, this problem occurs, and if the direct amount of the search in question is not used, the problem does not arise and it works correctly (index Seek).

Answer (score 0):

What way do you have your indexes? What column and that is under each index? I would assume you haven't indexed correctly or in a way that best suits your query as sql automatically uses the best and most efficient search when ran.

Comment: as i say, type and patentID set as non-cluster index in CommentTable